# How to delete an object after drag? jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have code that checks if a `td` has and image in it because i want to move a figure.
I want to move my figure more than once, but only where there is not another figure. But when i try to move my figure back to the starting position it does work. Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#king").draggable();
  $("td").droppable({
      stop: function(event, ui)
      {
        ui.draggable.remove();
      },
      drop: function(event, ui) {
if($(event.target).find('img').length >0)
      {
          $(ui.draggable).draggable({revert:true});
      }else 
      {
        $(ui.draggable).draggable({revert:false});
        var $this = $(this);
          ui.draggable.position({
          my: "center",
          at: "center",
          of: $this,
        using: function(pos) {
          $(this).animate(pos, 200, "linear");
        }
      });
      }
  }
});
});
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px black solid;
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
}
img{
  width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="drop_one"><img src="http://www.houseofchess.com/images/chess_pieces/wooden_staunton/shared/216777-375/nqw.jpg" id="king"></td>
  <td id="drop_two"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="drop_one"><img src="http://www.houseofchess.com/images/chess_pieces/wooden_staunton/shared/216777-375/nqw.jpg" id="king"></td>
  <td id="drop_two"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you see i tried to delete it after stop, but that's just stupid attempt. How can i delete image from starting position so i can go back to it? Or should i change my if to check on different way does field has an image in it?

Comment: this dynamic seems more appropriate for sortable rather than draggable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs due to the fact that you did not actually remove the image from the original `td`, merely repositioning it to the location of the new `td`. To the DOM, it is still the child of the original `td`, hence when you `find('img')`, it'll see an image (which is actually itself) is in that drop zone.

What you can do is to actually relocating the image to the new `td`. This can be achieved by `detach`ing it from the original `td` and `appendTo` the new `td`. I did that after the animation is completed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".king").draggable();
  $("td").droppable({
      drop: function(event, ui) {
          if($(event.target).find('img').length > 0)
          {
              $(ui.draggable).draggable({revert:true});
          } else {
              $(ui.draggable).draggable({revert:false});
              var $this = $(this);
              ui.draggable.position({
                  my: "center",
                  at: "center",
                  of: $this,
                  using: function(pos) {
                      $(this).animate(pos, 200, "linear", function() {
                          $(this).detach().appendTo($this);
                          $(this).css({ top: '2px', left: '2px'});
                      });
                  }
              });
          }
      }
  });
});
```

```css
table#board {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#board tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even), #board tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #663300;
}

td {
    border: 1px black solid;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
img {
    width: 46px;
 height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="board">
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.houseofchess.com/images/chess_pieces/wooden_staunton/shared/216777-375/nqw.jpg" class="king"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.houseofchess.com/images/chess_pieces/wooden_staunton/shared/216777-375/nqw.jpg" class="king"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this solves my problem. That's what i was looking for. Thanks again.